# How to set umask for a samba mount?

Tags: linux, macos, mount, samba

On linux (Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid) I want to mount a samba share to a remote Mac (OSX) such that files created on the share have full read/write permissiona across user/group/other (like umask 0)

```
# umask 0
# date > foobar
# ls -l foobar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 29 2014-11-07 21:13 foobar
```

Looks good on my local drive, so now I want that permissision to files I create on the share:

```
# mount -t cifs //imac/shared /mnt/imac -o username=admin -o mode=0,umask=0,uid=ubuntu,gid=ubuntu
# cd /mnt/imac
# date > foobar
# ls -l foobar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 29 2014-11-07 21:14 foobar
```

Didn't work!  How do I get the permissions to be 666 on the OSX share?